# No matter what I do, I can't get the table elements to touch

Tags: html, css, css-tables

So I'm designing an org chart based on the table element and I have a problem. I'm using `<hr>` elements to create the connectors; however, I can't get the dead space inbetween elements to go away. I've spent the last hour trying to figure out how the hell to get it to work and I just can't seem to figure it out.

I've included a picture to show:

[image]

The other issue is more of a question I haven't really looked into but figured I'd ask anyway. How can I lock the height of my table items. I've locked the width just fine but I can't seem to lock the height to 70px.

And here is some choice code:

```
<table class="orgchart" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td class="item"><a href="#director">Director</a></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="divider"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><hr width="1" size="20"></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td class="item">Assistant to the Director</td><td></td><td class="item">Deputy Director</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
```

And the CSS:

```
.orgchart td {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: no-wrap;
}

.divider td {
  height: 20px;
}

.item {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

And here is the CodePen: http://codepen.io/jacob_johnson/pen/GpEjmm?editors=110

Comment: The browser is applying default margins to the hr tag via the user agent stylesheet. You need to zero the top/bottom margins out for the hr and the dead space disappears

Comment: Thanks, guys. I can't believe I didn't think about the `<hr>`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a `margin` all the way around the `<hr>`. Remove the top and bottom margins from the `<hr>`. All browsers apply default styling to elements, though not always the same. As a result you will see reset and normalize stylesheets used to improve visual consistency and development pains.

[Updated Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOjqjP?editors=110) with CSS below added.

```
hr {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

If I was doing this project I would find a simple grid framework to layout with DIVs or more than likely I would create this chart as an inline SVG.

Comment: God I feel so stupid now... And do you have any recommendations of grid frameworks? I've been hunting for better solutions to do this org chart but I can't find anything...

Comment: There are a ton of CSS grid frameworks out there; [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) and  [Skeleton](http://getskeleton.com/) to name a few. Bootstrap and Foundation might have a little more than you need as they provide a lot of UI features. Thoug you can pick out the parts that you need and not use the whole framework. While Skeleton is more bare bones that you build on top of yourself.